# Proof of Poincaré's Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis

I am trying to go about a proof of Poincaré's Lemma in analysis, and I
    am having some difficulty with the proof. I would like to prove that if
    $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set that is starshaped with respect
    to a point $\epsilon$ and let $\mathbf{g} : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$
    be an irrotational vector field of class $C^1$, Then $\mathbf{g}$ is a
    conservative vector field.

I initialized this proof by setting
    $$f(\mathbf{x}) = \int_{\gamma} \mathbf{g}, \mathbf{x} \in U,$$
    where $\gamma$ is the cure given by the parametric representation
    $\phi : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^n$ defined by $\phi(t)
= \epsilon + t(\mathbf{x} + \epsilon)$. My friend then recommended that
    I recognize that
    $$f(\mathbf{x}) = \int_0^1 \sum_{j=1}^n g_j(\epsilon + t(\mathbf{x}
+ \epsilon))(x_j - x_{0,j}) dt,$$
   I am having difficulty seeing where I can get this result.
    Any recommendations on how to prove the previous statement, and how I
    may continue to finish this proof?

Comment: Can you write down the definition of $\mathbf{g}, \mathbf{x}$?

Comment: This follows from the definition of a path intergral; you have a parametrisation $\phi$ of $\gamma$ so $\int_\gamma g=\int_0^1 g\cdot\phi'\;dt$.

Comment: btw I think $x+\epsilon$ should be $x-\epsilon$ so that $\phi(1)=x$. Also $x_{0,j}$ should be $\epsilon_j$.